# Orphaned CD-RW symbol in the Unity bar

Tags: 11.10, unity

I have an orphaned CD-RW symbol in the Unity bar which does not disappear again. How could I get rid of it (it's Oneiric)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right-clicking and clicking unmount?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Somehow only "Open" left ... but anyway it somehow disappeared after remounting/dismounting the same medium again.

Comment: Okay. That's kind of strange, but all well...